# Slight space appear depending on OS resolution and CSS position

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I am making the layout with border and nested div.

Those div tags have their own background color and able to move by key press.

It seems working fine, but when I change the laptop, 1px space appears between div tags.

[Image of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAFyV.png)

The reason is the OS scale and resolution change, but don't know how to solve this issue.

I would like NOT to make space in any OS scale and resolution.

---

The sample code is below.

https://jsfiddle.net/2cdr5yun/2/

If you move the box by keys, sometime the space appears and sometimes disappear.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

This issue occurs in Chrome, not in IE11.

---

Here's my environment.

1. Environment working OK

   - OS: Windows10
   - Display Resolution: 1366 x 768
   - Display Scale: 100%
2. Environment NOT working

   - OS: Windows10
   - Display Resolution: 1920 x 1080
   - Display Scale: 125%

---

```html
<body>
    <div class="box" id="box">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
body{
  position: relative;
}
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: orange;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner{
    background: blue;
    height: 100%; /* same result in 200px */
    width: 100%; /* same result in 200px */
}
```

Comment: oddly, when you set the `border-value` of `.box` to an even value, the problem doesn't appear

Comment: @marco_autiero  It may change the layout isn't it? Is there any solution to maintain border width same as now?

Answer (score 0):

I can not post comments, so I'll write an answer as suggestion:
It's dirty hack, but you can try using outline instead of border, add margin of 1px and decrease width and height by 2px each. I suppose it won't change your layout and problem seems to be gone.

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 198px;
    width: 198px;
    background: orange;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/43bz2s9r/3/